# What is Modernizr, Normalize and HTML5Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

when i download a free theme or a demo tutorial in the web. I just noticed that now a days i always see those modernizr, normalise, and boilerplate thingy.

I have researched them but still i cant understand what they do? Maybe you guys can explain more or maybe use an analogy to explain it better.

It's like "Explaining New Web Development thingy for Dummies"  Really appreciate it.

Comment: I have researched them but still i cant understand what they do?  <-- means i googled them already. just want to hear stackoverflows side?

Comment: there is no way you have researched them and have no idea at all. Ask more specific questions

Comment: what do you mean there is no way? I can just google them right? that's common sense. again.. i would like to hear stackoverflow's people side.. not those posts in the web. from my understanding ..1.  normalise is like reset.css just a better one 2. modernzr lets jquery's and javascripts run on all browsers 3. html5 bioler plate is like a starter theme that includes the 2 already..

Comment: also, i asked this question not just for me..  but for all beginners out there who googles what is normalize, mordernzr and html5 bioler plate .. they might come across this question

Comment: Exactly the question I want to ask - no idea why it's been closed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Due to the differences in browsers and platforms, these libraries try to make is so that you don't have to use browser-specific code to take advantage of all the new HTML5 features.

Another way of saying it is, since all browsers "interpret" the HTML5 standard differently, these libraries help to smooth out the differences between interpretations.

Modernizr: http://modernizr.com/

> Taking advantage of cool new web technologies is great fun, until you have to support browsers that lag behind. Modernizr makes it easy for you to write conditional JavaScript and CSS to handle each situation, whether a browser supports a feature or not. It’s perfect for doing progressive enhancement easily.

Boilerplate: http://html5boilerplate.com/ (If this is the one you are referring to)

> HTML5 Boilerplate helps you build fast, robust, and adaptable web apps or sites. Kick-start your project with the combined knowledge and effort of 100s of developers, all in one little package.

Basically this gives you a framework for laying out your webpages so you don't have to start from scratch every time.

Normalize.css: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ (Again, assuming this is the one you're talking about)

> Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

Basically, this CSS file allows you to write standard CSS and then it helps to render it consistently in all browsers.

**TL;DR Version**
These frameworks/files make it so that you can focus on writing standard-compliant website code (HTML5, CSS or JS) without having to worry about browser-specific tweaks.  In addition, a front-end framework like Boilerplate gives you some nice "style-helpers" to make your website look great from the start.

Comment: thanks! now i want to know if most of the developers use this?? or do you/ do they prefer to code it from scratch

Comment: The nice thing about these tools is they still allow you to code things from scratch. What you'll find if you don't use these tools is that you'll start running in to the same problems over and over again that have been solved either over years of people coming up with solutions to it, or by the number of smart people that have come together to figure out the best solution. definitely no shame in coding from scratch, and you could benefit from that by a deeper understanding of browsers and markup.

Comment: We use modernizr at the firm I work for. We use twitter bootstrap for a lot of css templating, which if I'm not mistaken also has a css reset integrated. We don't use boilerplate due to the nature of client projects. In many cases they select the preferred platform and we use the boilerplates those platforms provide, or one we have generated. Like a wordpress or drupal theme, for example.

Comment: Thanks!!! Now i know those 3 i asked are worth learning..

Comment: It's becoming more common for developers to use these.  As @keithwyland said, you can still do things from scratch and it will help you learn why things are the way they are.  After you create some sites from scratch, you'll see why these libraries exist.

Comment: These are definitely worth learning.  You'll soon see there are a lot of options out there beyond these as well. Each have their own group of supporters. A lot of it becomes personal preference, or even what one you started using first. Once you get comfortable how a library works, it really can speed up your workflow.

Comment: It really depends on what type of programmer/designer you are. I prefer to do things myself, so I write everything myself. If you're new to web development I highly recommend looking into these projects to help lift your projects off the ground quickly and safely.

Comment: Similar to Jazza, I would agree that these tools are useful, but not the holy grail of development. The concepts behind them are definitely need-to-use concepts, but be it browser capability detection, CSS resets, or a simple boilerplate, you have to find what works for you. If these tools all do it for you, then go for it, but don't constrain yourself to just these.